# DigitalOcean App Platform not finding Vue.js Quasar dependency

Tags: node.js, vue.js, deployment, digital-ocean, quasar

I encountered an issue when trying to host my Vue.js Quasar web application on the app platform as a web service. My app has the Quasar CLI as a dependency (provides the build and serve commands), and everything I’m trying to do on the app platform works locally. On local, I run `npx quasar build` (build command) followed by `npx quasar serve dist/spa -p 9000 --history` (run command). When I set these commands as build / run in DigitalOcean, my deployment fails saying it cannot find the "serve" command:

```
[2022-12-22 10:39:45]  Browser target......... es2019|edge88|firefox78|chrome87|safari13.1
[2022-12-22 10:39:45]  =======================
[2022-12-22 10:39:45]  Output folder.......... /workspace/dist/spa
[2022-12-22 10:39:45] 
[2022-12-22 10:39:45]  Tip: Built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server
[2022-12-22 10:39:45]       Opening index.html over file:// won't work
[2022-12-22 10:39:45] 
[2022-12-22 10:39:45]  Tip: You can use "$ quasar serve" command to create a web server,
[2022-12-22 10:39:45]       both for testing or production. Type "$ quasar serve -h" for
[2022-12-22 10:39:45]       parameters. Also, an npm script (usually named "start") can
[2022-12-22 10:39:45]       be added for deployment environments.
[2022-12-22 10:39:45]       If you're using Vue Router "history" mode, don't forget to
[2022-12-22 10:39:45]       specify the "--history" parameter: "$ quasar serve --history"
[2022-12-22 10:39:45] 
[2022-12-22 10:39:47]  App • Looking for Quasar App Extension "serve" command "dist/spa"
[2022-12-22 10:39:47]  App • ⚠️  Quasar App Extension "serve" is missing...
```

I’ve double checked, and the Quasar CLI is in fact in my package.json. I even tried setting the build command in DigitalOcean to `npm install @quasar/cli; npx quasar build` with no luck. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and here are my settings on DigitalOcean, which works for me.
In your dashboard go to Apps > choose your app > Settings > select your component > scroll down

1. Output Directory: `dist/spa`
2. Custom Pages: `index.html`  *you probably do not need this*
3. Build Command: `yarn global add @quasar/cli; npx quasar build --history`

If you are using npm instead of yarn, change `yarn global add @quasar/cli` with `npm install -g @quasar/cli`.
If you are not using the history mode in your project, you do not need `--history` on number 3.